# How to keep uppercase when passing parameters from url into whatsapp api web?

Tags: html, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have a problem here. Here is my sample code:
`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=[International Ph. Number]&text=GoodMorning!`

Copy the following codes and insert into any browser and change the [International Ph. Number] to any international phone number. What's the problem here is when showing in the api.whatsapp.com, they were fine but when passing into https://web.whatsapp.com/ all my uppercase turned into lowercase! I even tried url encoding such as the % still doesn't work for me.

Comment: this is serious... I was sending a token and now that token doesn't work any more. :(

Comment: did you start bounty ?

Comment: Sorry. I am YET not qualified to do so.

Comment: i think, whatsapp converts input from api to lowercase while filtering variables.

Comment: @santosh Well, my thought exactly. But due to certain issues, I would have to retain the uppercase. I raised this issue to WhatsApp via third party and wished that they could look into it (by all mean). Otherwise, I may have to come out with possible solutions by myself (which I don't at the moment).

Comment: I communicated with WhatsApp team and they replied that they will be solving this bug in the future release, though they did not inform me any tentative date for their any future releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed internally by WhatsApp, update will be pushed out soon (see thread: https://whatsappen.com/whatsapp-click-to-chat)

EDIT 12/08/2017: it's fixed since a couple of days. Try: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=&text=SomeCapitalLetters